# Python tkinter make row full weight on screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a gui full screen. Is working as full screen but i am not able to do the followings :

1 - first row (row 0) to be scaled to max width of screen

2 - on row 1, the first and last column have fixed width and stay on left and right of the screen (this is working)

3 - the empty labels between buttons to be on the center

4 - the 2 buttons to be center aligned  in left and right

This is my code till now:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        #line 0
        label0 = tk.Label(self, text = 'full row', height=3, borderwidth=1)
        label0.configure(relief='raised')
        label0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=12)

        # line 1
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='0', width=10)
        label1.configure(relief='raised', bg='white')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')

        buttonhlp = tk.Button(self, text="HELP", command=close_window)
        buttonhlp.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=5)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=6)

        buttonquit = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=close_window)
        buttonquit.grid(row=1, column=7, columnspan=4)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='11', width=10)
        label1.configure(relief='raised', bg='white')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=11, sticky='e')


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()




def close_window ():
    app.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()

    app.overrideredirect(True)
    app.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(app.winfo_screenwidth(), app.winfo_screenheight()))
    app.focus_set()  # <-- move focus to this widget


    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure is the best solution but i made it work like this

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=12,sticky="nsew")
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(8, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(11, weight=1)



        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        #line 0
        label0 = tk.Label(self, text = '')
        label0.configure(relief='raised')
        label0.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=12, sticky="nsew")

        # line 1
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='0', width=10)
        label1.configure(relief='raised', bg='white')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')

        buttonhlp = tk.Button(self, text="HELP", command=close_window)
        buttonhlp.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='xx')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=5)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='tt')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=6)

        buttonquit = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=close_window)
        buttonquit.grid(row=1, column=7, columnspan=4)

        label1 = tk.Label(self, text='11', width=10)
        label1.configure(relief='raised', bg='white')
        label1.grid(row=1, column=11, sticky='e')





class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()




def close_window ():
    app.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()

    app.overrideredirect(True)
    app.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(app.winfo_screenwidth(), app.winfo_screenheight()))
    app.focus_set()  # <-- move focus to this widget


    app.mainloop()
```